# How to Configure Swagger in .NET Core 2.2 WebApi and Azure AD 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with the "authorize" functionality of the Swagger to authenticate a WebApi application using Azure AD 2.0 endpoint. I used the following settings in my startup class, but the acquired token fails to validate the bearer token inside the Swagger. The API works fine with the token sent by the react client.

```
private const string AzureAdConfigKey = "AzureAd";
private const string OAuth2Definition = "openid";

private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
private IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    Environment = environment;
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind(AzureAdConfigKey, options));

    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme,
        options => options.Authority += "/v2.0");

    var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy)))
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    var azureAdAuthority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0";
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Title = "My Api Name",
            Version = "v1"
        });

        options.AddSecurityDefinition(OAuth2Definition, new OAuth2Scheme
        {
            Description = "OAuth2 Implicit Grant",
            Flow = "implicit",
            AuthorizationUrl = $"{azureAdAuthority}/authorize",
            TokenUrl = $"{azureAdAuthority}/connect/token",
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {OAuth2Definition, "User.Read"}
            }
        });

        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {{OAuth2Definition, null}});
    });

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder => builder
        .WithOrigins(Configuration["MyAppClientUrl"])
        .AllowCredentials()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
    ));

    // Other Service Registrations.
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
    {
        const string swaggerName = "MyApp Coding Api";
        const string swaggerUrl = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";

        config.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerUrl, swaggerName);
        config.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

        config.OAuthAppName(swaggerName);
        config.OAuthClientId(Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]);
        config.OAuthClientSecret(Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]);
        // This is my Api local path.
        config.OAuthRealm("https://localhost:44398/swagger/ui/o2c-html");
        config.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
    });

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The following is the token generated by the client, which works fine and implements .v2.0:

```
{
  "aud": "{Excldued}",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Excldued}/v2.0",
  "iat": 1556730915,
  "nbf": 1556730915,
  "exp": 1556734815,
  "aio": "AVQAq/8LAAAA9lULrpdFyoAfnaWTCkdo8PMz2vL4C0MbDNAxmRBa3rMETsjpnXYFb5izdF/VRWMLzOvwgmw9Zt3zzisWRbLCFMd5KAaJ59wUDqNdSoawS6U=",
  "name": "{Excldued}",
  "nonce": "{Excldued}",
  "oid": "{Excldued}",
  "preferred_username": "{Excldued}",
  "roles": [
    "Coder",
    "Supervisor"
  ],
  "sub": "Jn0w0rhsGpwTKPdSjQBLHeHDv2_TD4kaOjo0x06JWKQ",
  "tid": "{Excldued}",
  "uti": "pOW4Q_EBdkSv_q0-OHRSAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

But the swagger generates the following token, which is .v1.0:

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{Excluded}/",
  "iat": 1556733552,
  "nbf": 1556733552,
  "exp": 1556737452,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AUQAu/8LAAAA9YXDyeK8KuCHbNgw7RGU8GgJk3qpWB1H+Q3i/dC/VRoAtYvp3NHFIYcTFxn3jfTPvvXRWx5MN35kvO0iCK7ftg==",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "{Excluded}",
  "appid": "{Excluded}",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "family_name": "{Excluded}",
  "given_name": "{Excluded}",
  "ipaddr": "{Excluded}",
  "name": "{Excluded}",
  "oid": "{Excluded}",
  "onprem_sid": "{Excluded}",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "{Excluded}",
  "scp": "openid profile User.Read email",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "{Excluded}",
  "tid": "{Excluded}",
  "unique_name": "{Excluded}",
  "upn": "{Excluded}",
  "uti": "{Excluded}",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "{Excluded}"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1361394419
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my Swagger configuration that requests 1.0 endpoint and gets the wrong token type?

### UPDATE:

This is the fiddler request to the Azure AD authorize endpoint:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={ClientId}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44350%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=openid&state={StateValue}&nonce=123456 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Referer: https://localhost:44350/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: Hey Saeid, is there anyway you can host this locally and get a fiddler/network trace to see what the Swagger is really doing? And if so, can you provide what the URL is that the swagger is going to? It looks like the configureservices method is setup properly so it should be going to the v2.0 endpoint,

Comment: Hey @FrankHu. I updated the question with the Fiddler request. The weird thing is that the API works fine with a client SPA app that authenticates using the MSAL library. It just doesn't work with Swagger or Postman. Thanks for checking this up though.

Comment: If you like, I can get you in touch with Technical Support to take a closer look. It might be useful to see the full fiddler trace. I'm not sure if that request is the Swagger request

You can email me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and include in the email a link to this thread, that way I can enable a free support request for you.

Comment: @Saeid how'd you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a v1.0 token is because you are trying to get access to a v1.0 resource. Please see the article here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

> Access tokens are created based on the audience of the token, meaning the application that owns the scopes in the token. This is how a resource setting accessTokenAcceptedVersion in the app manifest to 2 allows a client calling the v1.0 endpoint to receive a v2.0 access token. Similarly, this is why changing the access token optional claims for your client do not change the access token received when a token is requested for user.read, which is owned by the MS Graph resource.
>   For the same reason, while testing your client application with a personal account (such as hotmail.com or outlook.com), you may find that the access token received by your client is an opaque string. This is because the resource being accessed has requested legacy MSA (Microsoft account) tickets that are encrypted and can't be understood by the client.

Your v1.0 token has the audience for the Microsoft Graph, which is issued by the v1.0 endpoint. If you follow the article here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow 
You will see that even when hitting the v2.0 endpoint, and requesting an access token with Postman for the resource graph.microsoft.com you will get an access token where the iss doesn't have v2.0.

This is also a very useful resource as it's a nice reference to some popular GUIDs in Azure. : https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/